# How to change styling issue of rounded cornors in IOS?

Tags: html, ios, css, select, safari

In Safari/iOS 11 select dropdown appearance has styling issues. You can check the picture below. Please provide a fix for this as it is looking ugly on all apple devices.

[image]

**UPDATE: -**

Here is the bootstrap code which I am using

```css
.form-control-rounded {
    -webkit-border-radius: 1.875rem !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 1.875rem !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 1.875rem !important;
    -o-border-radius: 1.875rem !important;
    border-radius: 1.875rem !important;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group mb-4">
  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
  <select class="form-control-rounded form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your code? We're not here to do your work for you, we're here to `help`.

Comment: Update the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a webkit property :

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
```